# Captive Vine Snake not shedding correctly

Tags: skin-condition, snakes, shedding

(NOTE: This question is asked on behalf of a friend, who has a captive Vine Snake (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahaetulla_prasina), so "go see a vet" is not going to help here).

A week ago the snake had started to shed -- clearing the old skin from its upper head. But the old skin on the body (and lower-jaw) was not separating. It was clinging.

Usually there is a waxing process, which facilitates the slough, and gives the new scales a glisten.

However, a week later the old skin is coming off in patches, and the new scales are not waxed.

Is anyone able to suggest possible causes for this?

I wonder if it could be a vitamin deficiency or maybe a lack of natural sunlight.

Grateful if someone is able to suggest possible causes/remedies.

Comment: I do not understand what prevents your friend of going to a vet? (No matter if it is needed or not)

Comment: You should add how the snake is homed. What temperature, what humidity, what kind of light bulb and so on...

Comment: @Allerleirauh It is not my snake, therefore not my decision/business. Snake is in a plastic tank (well-enough aired) in the shade in Thailand. So no lightbulb/heating. It's a humid jungle climate. Snake is an indigenous species.

Comment: Point 1: In most parts of the world it is not allowed / no good behavior to take native species from their environment and have them as pets. Point 2: If it is not a pet, bred for being a pet, then this question is out of scope of this site. Point 3: If the tank has a cover, not all ray types of sun would come through. So there might be a lack of vitamin D.